# Use V-IF and V-FOR in a HTML table (VUE3)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Hello guys I'm currently working on an Monitoring application for my company.
So I'm trying to use V-if and V-for in a table
My code looks like this:

```
   <tbody  v-for="server in servers" :key="server.Id">
      <tr v-if="server.Show == true">{{DATA}}</tr>
```

[image: Picture from the Monitoring Application]
If you click the red eye on the left side you can hide an Server, but it leaves the line there what it is not supposed to do. If I resize the window it'll correct it. Is there a nicer way to bring my data into the Tablebox because now I'm creating a new tablebody for each server

I'm still a student and pretty new to VUE so I hope someone can give me an explanation why this is happening.

EDIT: Spelling and a little bit of more Info

Comment: how do you handle the click event?

Comment: The code looks like this
  HTML: <td><img src="../assets/eye.png" @click="HideServer(server)" /></td> 
  
VUE:  HideServer(server: { Show: boolean }) {
      server.Show = false;
    },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should loop over the servers in a template and hide the row inside

```js
<tbody>
  <template v-for="(server, index) in servers">
      <tr :key="server.Id" v-if="server.Show">{{DATA}}</tr>
        <td>
          <img src="../assets/eye.png" @click="HideServer(server,index)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
   </template>
</tbody>
```

Comment: If I try using it says "property does not exist", also I got a <th> that woud loop with it

Comment: I guess 'index' does not exist because I removed it from the `v-for`. I will update my example

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you, you want to make the same without tbody tag?
In this case, you can replace tbody with template tag, this tag won't be rendered, it would be the same than make v-for and v-if at the same line.

```
<template  v-for="server in servers">
  <tr v-if="server.Show == true" :key="server.Id">{{DATA}}</tr>
```

Comment: Well you're right I dont want to use the <tbody> tag, but the main problem is the line it leaves behind when I hide an object. It just seems like a good solution to create a new body for each server, instead of just using a <tr>

Comment: Oh, you want the line space hiding data? So you can do it with opacity style instead removing it. You can set a class with condition :class="{'opacity-0': server.Show}" and define to that class .opacity-0{ opacity: 0 } in your css

Comment: Unfortunately, the result remains the same, the line is still displayed.

Comment: Using the template instead of tbody and the class at tr?

Comment: Well I cant just use it in the template since I got a <th> and if I try using it  says "property does not exist"

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the index to modify the corresponding item :

```html
 <tbody  v-for="(server,index) in servers" :key="server.Id">
      <tr v-if="server.Show == true">.....
        <img src="../assets/eye.png" @click="HideServer(server,index)" /></td>
```

```js
  
HideServer(server,index) {
  this.servers[index]={...server,Show : false}

 }
```

Comment: 'Property '$set' does not exist on type' do you have an idea wheres the problem here?

Comment: are you using vue 2 or 3?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad I'm using Vue3 gonna edit it right now

Comment: please check my edited answer

Comment: Unfortunately, the result remains the same, the line is still displayed. Could it have to something with the rendering since they are remove/corrected once the window is resized?